# Create a grid of NDVI maps from different dates

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2

I want to create a grid of 4 NDVI maps from different dates with the same parameters so I can check variance over a period

I tried to change an example named 'Linked Maps' in User Interface folder in order to do so, but I only get 4 empty maps without any layers
I still need to use inspector to see the NDVI value in each map (once I click a point in a map) in order to adjust the visualisation paramters for all the maps

```js
var img1 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180302T081839_20180302T083044_T36SYB');
var img2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180307T081801_20180307T081804_T36SYB');
var img3 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180312T081729_20180312T082903_T36SYB');
var img4 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180317T081651_20180317T082118_T36SYB');

var img1_ndvi = img1.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var img2_ndvi = img2.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var img3_ndvi = img3.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var img4_ndvi = img4.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);

var IMAGES = [ 'img1_ndvi',
              'img2_ndvi', 
              'img3_ndvi', 
              'img4_ndvi'];

var NAMES = ['Last NDVI Image',
             'Second last',
             'Third last', 
             'Four last'];

var vis_params = {min: 0.1, max: 0.6, palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D,     F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
    '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'};

var maps = [];
IMAGES.forEach(function(image, name, index) {
  var map = ui.Map();
  map.add(ui.Label(name));
  map.addLayer(IMAGES[index], vis_params, name);
  map.setControlVisibility(false);
  maps.push(map);
});

var linker = ui.Map.Linker(maps);
// Enable zooming on the top-left map.
maps[0].setControlVisibility({zoomControl: true});
// Show the scale (e.g. '500m') on the bottom-right map.
maps[3].setControlVisibility({scaleControl: true});
// Create a title.
var title = ui.Label('NDVI maps for the Last 4 Images', {
  stretch: 'horizontal',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '16px'
});
// Create a grid of maps.
var mapGrid = ui.Panel(
  [
    ui.Panel([maps[0], maps[1]], null, {stretch: 'both'}),
    ui.Panel([maps[2], maps[3]], null, {stretch: 'both'})
  ],
  ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {stretch: 'both'}
);
// Add the maps and title to the ui.root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([title, mapGrid]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
maps[0].setCenter(35.07, 31.8, 6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things I spotted:

1) In your array `IMAGES` you use strings for the names of the images, but those are not automatically cast to the objects - use the variable names directly.

2) It's easier if you loop over the `NAMES` list, like in the example.

Working version of your code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a12bf01f9231c36bfbb13c022887f0ad

```js
var img1 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180302T081839_20180302T083044_T36SYB');
var img2 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180307T081801_20180307T081804_T36SYB');
var img3 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180312T081729_20180312T082903_T36SYB');
var img4 = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2/20180317T081651_20180317T082118_T36SYB');

var img1_ndvi = img1.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var img2_ndvi = img2.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var img3_ndvi = img3.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);
var img4_ndvi = img4.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4']);

var IMAGES = [ img1_ndvi,
              img2_ndvi, 
              img3_ndvi, 
              img4_ndvi];

var NAMES = ['Last NDVI Image',
             'Second last',
             'Third last', 
             'Four last'];

var vis_params = {min: 0.1, max: 0.6, palette: 'FFFFFF, CE7E45, DF923D,     F1B555, FCD163, 99B718, 74A901, 66A000, 529400,' +
    '3E8601, 207401, 056201, 004C00, 023B01, 012E01, 011D01, 011301'};

var maps = [];
NAMES.forEach(function(name, index) {
  var map = ui.Map();
  map.add(ui.Label(name));
  map.addLayer(IMAGES[index], vis_params, name);
  map.setControlVisibility(false);
  maps.push(map);
});

var linker = ui.Map.Linker(maps);
// Enable zooming on the top-left map.
maps[0].setControlVisibility({zoomControl: true});
// Show the scale (e.g. '500m') on the bottom-right map.
maps[3].setControlVisibility({scaleControl: true});
// Create a title.
var title = ui.Label('NDVI maps for the Last 4 Images', {
  stretch: 'horizontal',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '16px'
});
// Create a grid of maps.
var mapGrid = ui.Panel(
  [
    ui.Panel([maps[0], maps[1]], null, {stretch: 'both'}),
    ui.Panel([maps[2], maps[3]], null, {stretch: 'both'})
  ],
  ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal'), {stretch: 'both'}
);
// Add the maps and title to the ui.root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([title, mapGrid]);
ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('vertical'));
maps[0].setCenter(35.07, 31.8, 6);
```